# how to use JSF 1.2 and JPA in Netbeans?

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, jpa

I'm trying to use JPA to connect my JSF components to database but the problem is that I can't figure out how to get this all combination works.I have done entity classes from database, also create persistence.xml file and now I don't know where to go!! I don't know how to use entity manager and entity manager factory.

Is there any tutorial helps me how to use Java EE 5,JSF 1.2 and JPA in netbeans?

any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tutorial on the Netbeans site about [using JPA & JSF1.2 with Hibernate](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-jpa.html).  Hopefully that'll be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks but this so simple and generate jsf pages automatically. For me I have jsf pages created but I want to connect them to database

Answer (score 0):

You can download this [sample application](http://www.box.net/shared/hxb7yeum17) mentioned in this [blog](http://monstersandwich.blogspot.com/2010/01/shopping-cart-web-application-part-7.html). It runs on GlassFish but it is an Eclipse project. You can easily [import](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/import-eclipse.html) the Eclipse project into NetBeans.